# replacing kernel on non-booting ec2 instance

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, amazon-ec2

So I had an amazon ec2 instance crash during the update to 14.04LTS. Frustratingly, it appears the kernel might be bad (or at least that's what the log below says to me, I could totally be wrong). I'm able to mount the volume to another, working server, chroot the broken volume, and `sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.MOSTRECENT`. Unfortunately though, when I try `sudo update-grub`, it comes back with

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).
```

What am I missing?

Here's the log from the server's attempted bootup:

> ```
> [H[J  Booting 'Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, memtest86+'
>
>
>
> root  (hd0)
>
>  Filesystem type is ext2fs, using whole disk
>
> kernel  /boot/memtest86+.bin
>
>
>
> ============= Init TPM Front ================
> Tpmfront:Error Unable to read device/vtpm/0/backend-id during tpmfront initialization! error = ENOENT
> Tpmfront:Info Shutting down tpmfront
> xc: error: panic: xc_dom_core.c:621: xc_dom_find_loader: no loader found: Invalid kernel
> xc_dom_parse_image returned -1
>
> close(3)
>
>
> Error 9: Unknown boot failure
>
>
>
> Press any key to continue...
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8DsR1P7cbQ&feature=share&list=UUiu3bwoy2wcD9OYEFxuHp1A&t=11m49s) I hope it's what you need.

Comment: Checking it out now. It's looking promising, although ec2 instances are a little funny with their virtual drives. I'm hoping it'll work! Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I was able to install a new kernel, but i'm still getting the same boot errors. I'm pretty unsure where to turn.